# Is this the correct interpretation of x86-64 shift instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, shift

```
movl    %eax, %edx           
sarl    $31, %edx            
shrl    $31, %edx
```

I have the above x86-64 code.  I am interpreting this to mean that sarl will shift the value of edx (which is the equivalent of eax) to the right arithmetically, meaning the most significant bit will fill 31 of the 32 bits out of the register, filling in from the right.

Then, shrl, fills the 31 most significant bits with 0, leaving 1 lone bit in the edx register.  This bit will read '0' if eax was positive and '1' if eax was negative.

Is this the correct interpretation, or am I grasping this concept incorrectly?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: Seems easier to do `and $0x80000000, %edx` but perhaps the shifting back and forth is faster because there is no big immediate constant.

Comment: Thanks guys.  This is a file I am supposed to 'read' for homework so I cannot change it.  My confusion came from the fact that I feel like the 'sarl' instruction is not necessary.  Perhaps the instructors created this with a compiler and did not 'tidy' it up?

Comment: An alternative to the shrl $31,%edx would be a neg %edx (so that -1 becomes +1, and 0 remains 0).

Comment: @GregHewgill immediate constant in x86_64 is maximum 4 bytes except for movabs where it's 8 bytes